# BUG Bus Error ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm getting an error after compiling Ruby 1.8.7 using RVM on Lion 10.7.1 with Xcode 4.2 GM (new MacBook).

It compiles fine but when I try to install any gem I get the following:

```
gem install bundler
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:60: [BUG] Bus Error
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-darwin11.1.0]

Abort trap: 6
```

**Update**: In the end I hope to have Xcode 4.2 installed, RVM with Ruby 1.8.7, 1.9.x installed and all working properly.

Comment: [This seems related](http://jalada.co.uk/2011/07/24/lion-rvm-and-ruby-1-8-7-woes.html) - try the fix he used? Looks like a deepseated incompatibility of some sort.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since I had to parse through several of these answers to get things working with XCode 4.2, I thought I'd put it all together:

1. Install Xcode 4.2
2. Install the gcc standalone compiler from https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer (which replaces Xcode)
3. Add `export CC=gcc-4.2` to your ~/.bash_profile or equivalent (don't forget to reload it)
4. Run `rvm implode" then re-install rvm` http://beginrescueend.com/

At this point I was able to rvm install ruby-1.8.7 (and ruby-1.9.2), and actually get my gems to install.

Comment: Do you still have Xcode 4.2 installed? Where does that fit into the install steps?

Comment: it worked for me with Lion system (fresh installed) with Xcode 4.2.1.  However, can someone explain why this is the problem?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean it works without using the workaround with Xcode 4.2.1?  That would be good to know.  The issue happened because Apple changed the default compiler to the pure LLVM compiler in Xcode 4.2, and it looks like Ruby doesn't compile properly with it.  The default compiler section here has a bit more info: [Apple Xcode 4.2 docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_2.html).

Comment: Here is an explanation of why Xcode 4.2 doesn't work from Apple's release notes:


_The default compiler for iOS development in Xcode 4.2 is LLVM 3.0. Compared with the GCC compiler that was the default in Xcode 4.0 and the LLVM-GCC compiler in Xcode 4.1, LLVM provides better code generation and optimization than GCC, along with newer language support than LLVM-GCC, including support for ARC in Objective-C and for the new C++ standard, C++0x_

Essentially the new compiler in Xcode 4.2 doesn't have the same GCC compiler as previous versions and Ruby 1.9.2+ chokes using the LLVM only compiler.

Answer (score 3):

So nuking RVM (`rvm implode`) and reinstalling didn't make any difference. I ended up installing Xcode 4.2 and then installing the GCC compilers after which overrides the Xcode compilers.

Here are the steps for those Googling this.

1. Install Xcode 4.2.x
2. Install GCC standalone compilers from https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer

   Note: Xcode 4.3 beta was recently released. I'm testing if this fixes the compilation issues.

Comment: I have Xcode 4.3 and still had this problem. Fixed by installing the osx-gcc-installer mentioned here and the `CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm reinstall 1.8.7-p352`

Answer (score 2):

[Multiple](http://jalada.co.uk/2011/07/24/lion-rvm-and-ruby-1-8-7-woes.html) [articles](http://docwhat.org/2011/08/ruby-crashing-on-lion/) suggest that Ruby doesn't like being compiled with LLVM being involved. The stopgap measure is to thoroughly remove the RVM install – the linked articles say how – and then recompile Ruby with plain GCC. The real fix will have to come from Apple/LLVM or the Ruby team.

Answer (score 2):

I fix that by

1. installing Xcode 4.2.x,
2. adding `export CC=gcc` into ~/.bash_profile,
3. Reloading environment (`source ~/.bash_profile`),
4. executing `rvm install 1.9.3`,
5. executing `rvm ruby-1.9.3-rc1`,
6. executing `gem update --system` and finally
7. executing `gem install bundler`

The problem is with Xcode 4.2.x version. If you run `rvm get head` you will see this message "DO NOT use Xcode Version 4.2.x. It currently fails to build several rubies and gems...".

I don't have solution for ruby v1.8.7.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah. I was able to get 1.9.2 to compile fine. 1.9.3 needs the `export CC=gcc` in `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.rvmrc`. I was never able to get 1.8.7 to compile until I imploded RVM, uninstalled Xcode and installed the GCC standalone compilers. See my solution above.

Answer (score 1):

I need to use Xcode on this machine, so the standalone gcc wasn't quite going to do it for me.

Per other posters, I followed the suggestions at the end of the RVM update's release notes.

Note, I didn't need to remove RVM. I was successful with a removal of Xcode 4.2.1 (completely), and a reinstall of Xcode 4.1, then doing the `CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 rvm install 1.8.7` trick. In my case I put `export CC="/usr/bin/gcc-4.2"` in my profile to save some typing while also setting up various gems.

This also worked for Ruby Enterprise Edition (ree-1.8.7-2011.03) which had been failing as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can download find stand alone GCC installer instructions here: https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer

This gives you a non llvm based gcc installation without having to mess around with Xcode.

You can then use the command

```
 export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

This allows you to have the latest X Code for OSX purposes and still have a happy gcc version for ruby.

Answer (score 0):

The rvm post-install documentation says:

> ** Lion Users: *DO NOT* use Xcode Version 4.2.x for OS X Lion. It currently fails to build several rubies and gems, as well as several Homebrew and Macports packages as well. Xcode Version 4.1 (4B110) works.
>   You can find Xcode 4.1 for OS X Lion at:
>   https://developer.apple.com/downloads/download.action?path=Developer_Tools/xcode_4.1_for_lion/xcode_4.1_for_lion.dmg

This worked for me.