# ruby-2.0.0-p353 [BUG] Bus Error while running rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-2.0

Whenever I run rspec, I get this long error message.

```
/Users/jkim/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks: [BUG] Bus Error
ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]
```

See the full error here.

http://hastebin.com/vuvucemawo.pas

Note that the rspec tests ran correctly.

What are some things I can try to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried recompiling your Ruby? Segfaults aren't likely a problem with RSpec, but something with your Ruby.

Comment: I tried it, but not working still. It's weird that it doens't work with `ruby-2.0.0-p195` as well

Comment: Can you post some code? Exactly what command are you running? What is your folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same issue.

Here is the full stack trace: https://gist.github.com/proxygear/8658364

I'm on a mac with `ruby-2.0.0-p353` installed via `rvm`
I don't get any bus error except when running spec (server, console work fine).

The closest error I found on stackoverflow is [BUG Bus Error ruby 1.8.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734344/bug-bus-error-ruby-1-8-7) but is connected with installing ruby more than runtime error.